# LAMPP Document Root Change

Tags: linux, xampp

I no longer wish to use /opt/lampp/htdocs/ as my lampp document root. I went into httpd.conf and edited it to reflect this, the new document root:

```
DocumentRoot "/home/work/Dropbox/Websites/"
Directory "/home/work/Dropbox/Websites/" (it has tags)
```

I type in `localhost/name_of_website_directory` and nothing shows. I even made a test.html file in the Websites directory - that won't load with `localhost/test.html` it just gives me a 403 and won't load a thing.

I restarted Apache and Lampp and cleared my browser cache, still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround it´s ok, try to check the logs, maybe there is something there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Hi, go to ex. /var/apache/logs and see the content of the file called error.log